# Scrollbar there, even though there is no content?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to get rid of the scrollbar for this [website](http://waldrausch-mit-katze.de/stofftier-shop/). The problem is, there is a scrollbar even though there is no visible content on the bottom. I tried body/html margin:0 but it didnt work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

There are two scrollbars, i need the main one (on the right) to behave normally, show only when it is actually needed.

I dont want to use overflow:hidden, because on smaller devices i need the scrollbar.

Comment: Hi.  Unfortunately we are unable to help if we cannot see or replicate your problem.  Could you please provide us with a jsFiddle where you encounter the problem so that we might be able to get a better idea of what you are struggling with?

Comment: @jae.phoenix Thats why i linked to the website. There are two scrollbars, the one on the right is showing even tho it is not needed.

Comment: Your outside scroller is copying the size of the content in your inner scrollbar, so you may have a duplicate ID or class.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the sizing of your background image.  Try resizing it.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. I can even remove the background, but I still get the scrollbar to nothing.